# How to get child views of RecyclerView which are not visible

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to get the views/view holder for the items of RecyclerView which are currently not visible in the list(I have scrolled down), like I scrolled to bottom and want the first child/item/row view.

I have tried using following methods but was unable to get the views/viewwHolder :

```
1. findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(position)
2. findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position)
3. recyclerView.getChildAt(position)
4. recyclerView.getLayoutManager().getChildAt(position)
5. Inside adapter I made viewholder.setIsRecyclable(false) but still didn't work.
```

All of these approaches worked on some devices but not on all Android devices like Oppo devices.
I need some fool proof solution for this, please help with that.

Comment: which are not visible ?i.e views  are not inflated yet .

Comment: why do you need a view which is not visible?

Comment: if possible please provide your xml layout for recylerview and code for recylerview adapter

Comment: Can you post your solutions and exceptions or results that they created?